# What component would likely be squirting water when GE cafe station door switch is activated?

Tags: water, pump

Recently purchased a used Cafe station side by side door ge refrigerator. Unfortunately it came with a few issues that I have been able to sort out. But I can not tell which internal door component is squirting water when the door water switch is activated? Has anyone else had this issue? The 2 resolved issues were a non functioning evaporator fan and impacted condenser coils! Any help or ideas would be appreciated. I have tried dozens of times to record the inside of the refrigerator with my phone while I activate the switch but I can never see where the leak is just the wet places left behind. I was thinking a pump seal but I'm not a appliance technician just a tinkerer of sorts!

Comment: Exact model number might be helpful. Does water spray inside or outside the fridge?

Comment: Maybe you have a leak at one of the hose connections.  Is it *only* when the door water switch is activated?  Is the switch for water only, or is it used for ice too via toggle?